# Помощь в изучении Си

Tags: c

Посоветуйте как максимально эффективно прогрессировать в Си, на каких темах сосредоточить внимание, как распределить время.Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Скорее всего, ответы на этот вопрос будут основаны на мнениях, а не на фактах и цитатах. Необходимо переформулировать его так, чтобы на него можно было дать объективный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле как и все остальное. Просто взять и изучить. Начать с основ, постепенно продолжить. Тут всегда помогут с конкретной проблемой. Удачи!

> на каких темах сосредоточить внимание

Можно начать с какой-нибудь книги для начинающих, она сама подскажет.

> как распределить время

Главное не спешить. ;) Если просто брать и последовательно учить — то все будет эффективно.

Comment: я бы хотел добавить пару советов: 1) Мне очень понртавилась книга Страуструпа "Язык программирования С++. Краткий курс". Это действительно не очень длинная, но насыщенная книга, которую полезно прочитать вдумчиво, пытаясь сделать примеры самостоятельно. Многие вопросы, с которыми я раньше шел на стеоверфлоу, она мне объяснила
2) Лично мне понравился Майерс - "Современный С++", по моему. Но я эту книгу пока до конца не одолел. Для чтения нужно достаточно беглое владение многими темами.

Comment: @S.H. вопрос о си, и вы просто не читали K&R =) Вот там все раскладывается по полочкам.

Comment: @mik.ov - мне кажется, у меня в детстве была синяя книжка по С. Она была на хорошей бумаге, в мягкой обложке, с цветным кодом и с небольшим кол-вом картинок, но я тогда был слишком юн, чтобы всё в ней понять :-) А про С - да, не обратил внимания.